# Is there a way to fetch table PK id value instead of foreign key value after Join? Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need to fetch my PK value.

Right now, the problem that I have is the value I am fetching is the foreign key. How can I fetch PK id value?

For visual representaion: Look at my problem

My UI and problem:
[image]

so all values are  `1` which is the value of foreign keys. How can I change it to `1` , `2` etc. which is PK id value?

My Model that has join query

```
public function get_questions($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('answers');
    $this->db->join('questions', 'answers.question_id = questions.id');
    $this->db->where('questions.id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $result = $query->result_array();
}
```

Controller

```
   public function edit($id)
    {   
        $data['questions'] = $this->post_model->get_questions($id);

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('teachers/edit', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');   
    }
```

See my table and the id I should fetch:

[image]

View

```
<?php echo form_open('posts/update'); ?>

            <!-- <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $posts['id']; ?>" /> -->
            Question:
            <input type="text" name="question" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $posts['question'];  ?>" /><hr>
            Answers:


            <?php foreach($questions as $question): ?>
                <input type="text" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $question['id']; ?>" /><hr>

                <input type="text" name="answer[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $question['answer']; ?>" /><hr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

            <hr>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save Changes">
</form>
```

Comment: What is the result when you print $data['questions'];?

Comment: @SandeepModak - hello, it prints the `Array();` can you help me with this?

Comment: @SandeepModak Precisely this is what it prints out `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [answer] => Yes [answer_id] => 1 [question_id] => 1 [correct] => 1 [type_id] => 0 [question] => Apple is color Red? ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [answer] => No [answer_id] => 2 [question_id] => 1 [correct] => 0 [type_id] => 0 [question] => Apple is color Red? ) )`

Comment: @SandeepModak is that what you need sir?

Comment: in your result what all are the columns coming from questions table

Comment: @SandeepModak - The inserted Questions. I am not sure what you meant by "columns coming"? I gave the array above I think that is the result? But is there a way for me to fetch the PK id? Instead of samw values of 1? Can my query modified?

Comment: @SandeepModak hello sir, can you provide or post a modifocation on my code?

Comment: does the answer posted below meet your expectation?

Comment: @SandeepModak - hello sir, unfortunately `answer_id` does not belong to my table. I just hard coded to assure that I the update is working fine and it does. but I neeed to get the PK key not the answer_id

Comment: @SandeepModak kindly disregard the `answer_id` as I just hard coded its value there is no way it can be incremented. Thank you sir.

Comment: try using $this->db->select('answers.id,answers.answer,answers.question_id,answers.correct,answers.type_id'); insted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
$this->db->select('answers.id,answers.answer,answers.question_id,answers.correct,answers.type_id');
    $this->db->from('answers');
    $this->db->join('questions', 'answers.question_id = questions.id');
    $this->db->where('questions.id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $result = $query->result_array();
```

to achieve results as per query

Comment: hello sorry, `answer_id` has a static value and it is not a primary key. I also removed it earlier because I am just hard coding it. but it has no way to increment or copy the PK id. sorry.

Comment: wow thank you never thought you can select selective data on join query. I missed out a lot about querying

Comment: You can get more help at Codeigniter Documention of query building https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: thanks man appreciate your help, I've thought an effective way of learning is to try a complex application